# Is Judoonian a language, and if so is there an official translation?

Tags: doctor-who, languages

I've been researching linguistics to help write a conlang, and I've taken an interest in Judoonian because of its unique use of vowel sounds.

I found a [translator online](http://www.judoon.com/), but it's clearly not official and doesn't work on any of the snippets of Judoonian from the show, such as from [this transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/29-1.htm).

> JUDOON: Blos so folt do no cro blo cos so ro.

Becomes either:

> blos sfolt dncro acos sr.

Or (trying to correct for mistranscription):

> asfdncro acsr.

I.e scrambled garbage when 'translated'.

But the page does imply that Judoonian is a simple cypher of English, which has been suggested elsewhere.

Is there a way of translating Judoonian either officially or unofficially, that isn't a simple cypher?

Comment: Sorry, why does that imply it's a cypher of English?

Comment: @Azor a cypher is when you make some algorithmic transformation on words or letters separate from context or grammar, rather than a translation

Comment: I'm aware. I don't understand how the evidence in your post means it's a cypher (I've done no other research), as opposed to random noises.

Comment: What I mean is the online translator I found was a cipher. I know that because the website explains how it works.

Comment: Ohhh, "it" refers to the translator. I thought you were referring to the whole thing in general.

Answer (score 10):

Out of universe, no - Judoon is not a language that has been created with any particular care and there is no way to translate the Judoon heard in the television programme.

There are a couple of Judoon 'translators' on the internet, and as far as I can tell, they are just a novelty. They each seem to use some kind of internal logic for the 'translation' process, perhaps an algorithm that ensures you get the same result from the same input, but the output from each site does not match.

For example, I ran the sentence "This is a test to see if it matches" through two Judoon translation sites:

- [This site](https://lingojam.com/JudoonTranslator) returned: "Slotho solololololo ooh test toh see fio ioh matches"
- [This site](http://www.judoon.com/judoon-translator.php) returned: "to ho kro so sho kro so sho blo sho to flo so to sho to plo sho so flo flo sho kro fo sho kro to sho mo blo to co ho flo so"

The latter site I used above does contain a rather detailed description of how English is 'translated' into Judoon:

> The Judoon translate by splitting words into individual letters then adding an "o" to all the letters.
> All Judoon word syllables start with a consonant.
> Judoon replace the vowels with the consonant that is closest to the vowel in the alphabet and then add a "C", "L" or an "R" etc. to it to make it a double.

All of which sounds very plausible, but if that is the logic used in the show then it ought to be able to translate dialogue from the show back into English.

In 'Fugitive of The Judoon', the first complete line of dialogue spoken after the Judoon teleport onto the college green is:

> So Zo Ro. To Sho Fro. So Zo To. No Fo Lo.

Running this through Whooligan's translator I get:

> szr .  t = .  szt .  nfl .

I've tried a few lines from the show, taken from transcripts online, and they all return rubbish, not English.

The limitation of the 'language' becomes obvious when you realise that there can only be 24 'words' in the language - the 24 consontant sounds in the English alphabet followed by the vowel 'o'.

It is worth mentioning that a Judoon appearing in 'Fugitive of The Judoon' was named 'Pol Con Don', and this was a tribute to real-life Paul Condon, a fan and friend of Chris Chibnall. If the language used in the show followed strict rules then they wouldn't have been able to make this out-of-universe tribute.

It is also worth mentioning that, IN-universe, Judoon is one language that the TARDIS translation matrix seems to ignore. Other aliens appear to speak English because the TARDIS telepathically translates for the Doctor's companions (and us, the audience), but Judoon language is never translated - the Judoon themselves have to 'assimilate' the language and use their own translators. It is reasonable to assume that their language could actually be some kind of encrypted communication.

Comment: The use of the latter site is part of my question, but I appreciate you looking into other translators.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Of course, but I compared it with another and used the other one I found (which explains its algorythm) to translate back too, so I feel I covered it more comprehensively. I think my in-universe point is the clinching blow really.

Comment: somehow I got so fixated on the translation examples I forgot you had an in-universe point at the end, that seems like a much more important point to labour.

Comment: Out-of-universe, it seems as if Judoon-speak was just a premise for David Tennant to have some fun spouting rapid-fire jibberish - he/the Doctor shows (shows off?) that can speak it far faster than the Judoon themselves.